# How to use Java to create a facebook event with photo(png or jpg)

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to use Java to create a facebook event with photo(png or jpg)

Is there anyone can share the scope and value

Thanks a lot.

When I read the graph-api document, I still can not figure out the scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [RestFB](http://restfb.com/). The example below is taken from the truly excellent documentation on the website:

```
// Publishing an image to a photo album is easy!
// Just specify the image you'd like to upload and RestFB will handle it from there.
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(MY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
FacebookType publishPhotoResponse = facebookClient.publish("me/photos", FacebookType.class,
  BinaryAttachment.with("cat.png", getClass().getResourceAsStream("/cat.png")),
  Parameter.with("message", "Test cat"));

out.println("Published photo ID: " + publishPhotoResponse.getId());
```

Comment: You must have an error in your access token, or you are not properly passing in the file content: I've used identical code to publish data out of S3 into Facebook photo albums.